# What is the time/space complexity of scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment?

Tags: python

What is the time/space complexity of scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment?
It is also known as Hungarian problem

Comment: Here's the source code: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.8.0/scipy/optimize/_lsap_module.c#L36

Comment: @ddejohn why does the function name misalign?

Comment: That's the C code, which Scipy's library calls. Take a look at the documentation for your function. It's literally just a wrapper around a C function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment.html) for `scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment` states:

> This implementation [of a linear sum assignment solver] is a modified Jonker-Volgenant algorithm [as described in [this 2016 paper by David Krouse](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7738348)].

The paper itself states:

> For example, the algorithm of Jonker and Volgenant, which unbeknownst to many can be considered a particularly efficient variant of the Hungarian algorithm, has a complexity of `O(n^3)`.

They further state that:

> [T]he Jonker-Volgenant shortest augmenting path algorithm was chosen for implementation in this paper.

(This is important to note, as there are other algorithms discussed throughout the paper.)

The author makes no claim of an asymptotic runtime better than `O(n^3)`, so I would say that the runtime is `O(n^3)`.