# What is the time/space complexity of scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment if the cost is a rectangle with different length and width?

Tags: python, scipy, variable-assignment

What is the time/space complexity of scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment if the cost is a rectangle with different length and width?

I know it is O(n^3) when the cost is a square from [What is the time/space complexity of scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71121657/what-is-the-time-space-complexity-of-scipy-optimize-linear-sum-assignment)